# getting OutOfMemoryError for elasticsearch threadPool

Tags: java, spring-mvc, elasticsearch

I'm using below code to get the transport client from ES server. Now in case the server got down I'm getting OutOfMemoryError error in tomcat as the elasticsearch threadpool is not released. Please let me know how to handle ES threadpool.

```
public static Client getInstance() {
    String ipAddress = MessageTranslator.getMessage("es.cluster.ip");
    int transportClientPort = 0;
    String clusterName = MessageTranslator.getMessage("es.cluster.name");

    try {
        transportClientPort =
            Integer.parseInt(MessageTranslator
                .getMessage("es.transportclient.port"));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        transportClientPort = 9300;
        LogImpl.setWarning(ESClientFactory.class, e);
    }

    logger.debug("got the client ip as :" + ipAddress + " and port :"
        + transportClientPort);
    if (instance == null) {
        logger
            .debug("the client instance is null, creating a new instance");
        ImmutableSettings.Builder settings =
            ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder();
        settings.put("cluster.name", clusterName);
        settings.build();
        instance =
            new TransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                    ipAddress, transportClientPort));

        logger.debug("returning the new created client instance...");
        return instance;
    }
    logger
        .debug("returning the existing transport client object connection.");
    return instance;
}
```

Getting the below exception.

```
56 errors] with root cause org.elasticsearch.common.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

Error injecting constructor, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread   
    at org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool.<init>(Unknown Source)   while locating org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread   at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)   
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:640)  
    at org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool.<init>(ThreadPool.java:141) 
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor216.newInstance(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)  
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:54)   
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45) 
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42) 
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45) 
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:200)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
```

Comment: "in case the server got down" - Which server ? Elasticsearch or tomcat ? . Have you made any threadpool setting changes at Elasticsearch , if so , please let me know.

Comment: by server I mean elasticsearch server. I haven't made any changes in elasticsearch settings.

Comment: Can you see the paste the value that is going in for transportClientPort

Comment: This is the line from log...
26-12-2014 18:02:41,408 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-10] com.aricent.aricloud.es.service.ESClientFactory 69 - got the client ip as :10.203.238.139 and port :9300

Comment: I need more info... Can you give me the memory allocated to Elasticsearch , net memory on that system and the amount of memory being used.